# Compilation error in LuaTeX, but in runs in Lua

Tags: luatex

I want to create an example for the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) in LuaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new, babelshorthands=true]{german}

\newcommand{\wert}[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(#1)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
  function EEA(a,b)
    if b == 0 then return a, 1, 0 end
    d,s,t = EEA(b, a % b)
    x = s - (a//b) * t
    return d, t, x
  end
  p = 47
  q = 97
  d,x,y = EEA(p,q)
\end{luacode*}
We have $\wert{d} = \wert{p} \cdot \wert{x} + \wert{p} \cdot \wert{y}$.
\end{document}
```

Running the code on https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo works, but when I try LuaTeX, I get the error:

> Language ngerman already loaded; id is 8[\directlua]:4: unexpected symbol near 
> '/'. 
> \luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 } 
>
> l.20 \end{luacode*}

I thought *i* is connected with the percent sign, but

```
  function gcd(a,b)
    if b == 0 then return a end
    return gcd(b, a % b)
  end
```

works fine. How do I solve this?

I have LuaTeX version 1.0.4 and I just run `lualatex lua_test.tex`.

Comment: Here, with TeXLive 2021, I get the correct result ("We have 1 = 47 · −33 + 47 · 16.")...

Comment: TeXLive2021 currently features LuaTeX 1.13.2 as well as LuaHBTeX 1.13.2, which the latter employing the harfbuzz rendering engine. Both programs employ Lua 5.3.6, which features the integer division operator `//`, Versions of Lua prior to 5.3 do *not* feature this operator. TeXLive last featured a version of LuaTeX that was based on Lua 5.2.x in 2018. Is something stopping you from updating your TeX distribution by four generations (from TeXLive2017 to TeXLive2021)?

Comment: Does it actually report *"ngerman"*? Are you sure it isn't *"german"*? What is the "n" for?

Comment: @PeterMortensen as far as I know, it is the "new" german spelling, opposed to the one until early 90's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're with an older LuaTeX version: in TeX Live, TL2017 matches LuaTeX 1.0.4 and Lua 5.2. As you can see in the [documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.1), integer division (`//`) isn't supported and has been added from [Lua 5.3](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.1). Thus, either use `math.floor(a/b)` or update your current distribution so that Lua 5.3 and therefore `//` are available.